# Do these 2 paragraphs contain a metaphor anywhere?

Tags: metaphors, simile

> "My memory is like a film. That is why I am really good at remembering 
>   things, like conversations I have written down in this book, and what people were wearing, and what they smelled like, because my memory has a smelltrack
>   which is like a soundtrack.
>
> And when people ask me to remember something I can simply press Rewind and
>   Fast Forward and Pause like on a video recorder, but more like a DVD because I don't have to Rewind through everything in between to get to a memory of 
>   something a long time ago. And there are no buttons, either, because it is 
>   happening in my head."

I'm reading a book about a boy, and he claims he doesn't use metaphors. I stumbled upon the section of the book quoted above, which seems to contain a metaphor. Am I correct in saying that he used a metaphor, therefore contradicting himself? Or are there only similes in it?

Comment: Lots of similes, but whether there's a metaphor in there or not is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks, could you please explain why this is a matter of opinion?

Comment: Ouch, that is some painful reading. I don't really see any metaphors in there, just a lot of bad similes.

Comment: Speaking of painful, this puts me in mind of a...quip...I heard in college: "Haven't we metaphor? You don't look the simile."

Comment: Once you've said "like a film" then, eg, "my memory has a smelltrack" could be viewed is simply an extension of that simile rather than a stand-alone metaphor.  As I said, a matter of opinion.  (And the distinction between "simile" and "metaphor" is pretty artificial anyway.)

Comment: @HotLicks: A simile may be considered a type of metaphor, but not all metaphors are similes, because they don't all observe the form (a metaphor using the words 'like' or 'as' to compare dissimilar things or ideas). The broader rhetorical category is metaphor, but when a question such as the OP's posits the distinction, similes must be considered, for the purposes of discourse, as distinct from other types of metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're looking for a simple answer. The simple answer is yes, you're right. The passage in question contains at least one common, garden variety metaphor:

> ...my memory has a smelltrack...

"Smelltrack" is metaphorically used, and is in a metaphorical construction. The author did not say, for example, "...my memory has a facility *like* a smelltrack..." or "...my memory recalls smells *as if* following a smelltrack", and (almost) certainly the author's memory does not have a literal smelltrack.

I did not take the time to analyze the quoted passage thoroughly for other simple metaphors, but many other less simple metaphors do exist in the passage you quoted. Describing those metaphors in detail, however, would begin to complicate the simple answer immediately.

For an example outside the quoted work, but which is illustrative of the issues, consider the word 'metaphor' itself. The word can be regarded as a 'dead metaphor': etymologically, 'metaphor' came from Greek roots meaning 'to bear, carry' and 'along with'. From those roots used metaphorically, the contemporary sense of 'metaphor' derives.

You can see why some people think that language is itself, by nature, metaphorical: all words are popularly supposed to stand for something else. What words 'carry along' with them is presumed (sometimes) to be meaning. In this sense, 'metaphor' in language is inescapable.

Edit: To clarify, in the phrase

> my memory has a smelltrack which is like a soundtrack

the simile is "a smelltrack is like a soundtrack", while the metaphor is "memory has a smelltrack". That a simile follows the metaphor does not make the metaphor a simile.

Comment: I told my teacher that "...my memory has a smelltrack..." is a metaphor regardless of having the word "like" afterwards and she disagreed. Thanks! I knew I was right haha! Just a small question, do you have a formal education in higher level English? Perhaps a degree or something. I want to make sure that I can take your opinion over hers.

Comment: @gogobebe2: Yes, I have an advanced degree but, much more importantly, a lifetime of experience, including along with heaps of avid reading more than 35 years professional work in related fields. Wrapping a metaphor in a simile doesn't make the metaphor any less a metaphor. Suppose I start my book with this: "This book was written as if by a child." Does that make the rest of the book an extended simile containing no metaphors? The claim that it does makes nonsense of the distinction between simile and metaphor, a distinction which must be preserved for the question itself to make sense.